# Join two tables in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am having trouble understanding `JOIN`. I think, for me, the problem lies with actually understanding the logic of the query. What I am trying to do is select all of the status updates from a table named "post", but only the ones from users I am "following", and then display them in order by date. So, I have two databases which are set up like this:

posts

```
|post_id|user_id|post_body|date_upload|
|   1   |    4  | hey.    | 01/2/2012 |
```

follows

```
|relation_id|user_id|followee_id|
|   1       |    4  |     2     |
```

Could someone please explain how I should syntactically and logically set this up?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to do it with joins, but doing it the old fashion way is just "SELECT `posts`.`post_id`, `posts`.`userid`, `posts`.`post_body`, `posts`.`date_upload` FROM `posts`,`follows` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = `follows`.`user_id` AND `follows`.`user_id` = 4 ORDER BY `posts`.`date_upload` DESC"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll find this will work:

```
SELECT
  p.post_id, 
  p.user_id,
  p.post_body,
  p.date_upload
FROM
  posts p,
  follows f
WHERE
  f.user_id = 4 
    AND
  f.followee_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY
  p.date_upload DESC
```

Comment: You should SELECT from multiple tables if you want to __retrieve records__. You should JOIN two tables if you want to __match records__.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL convert this to exactly the same as if it was a join anyway?

Comment: @Airzooka - That was my impression too. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: I was actually never aware MySQL did that, I would have never guessed.  Disregard, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select posts.* 
from posts 
        join follows on (follows.user_id = posts.user_id) 
where followee_id = xxxx
```

Comment: Also remember, you might want to put the table name in front of _all_ fields, just in case an ambiguous case forms down the road.

Comment: I think `follows` should be joined on `followee_id` and `follows.user_id` matched against this user's id, since this user is the "follower".

Answer (score -1):

**Customers" table "**

```
CustomerID           CustomerName

1                    Alfreds Futterkiste

2                   Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados

3                   Antonio Moreno Taquería
```

**the "Orders" table:**

```
OrderID           CustomerID

10308                2

10309                37

10310                77
```

***********************ANSWER*******************

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

CustomerName
                                           OrderID

Alfreds Futterkiste                            -

Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados           10308

Antonio Moreno Taquería                      10365

```
         -                               10382

         -                               10351
```